# SocketIO emit functions logging but not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, chat

I am trying to make a basic chat app with socketIO, express, mongoDB, everything works ok.

The functionality I want is , the newest message is added and the message div is scrolled to the bottom, this works.

The appended message has this format:

```
 $("#textdiv").append(` <li class='blueText'> <img src="//unsplash.it/50/50"/> ${message.name} </li>  <p class='blueText'> ${message.message} </p> <span class='blueText'>Posted on: ${message.time.slice(0, 10) } <span class='spacial'> at: ${message.time.slice(11, 19) }</span> </span>`);
```

The timestamp worked ok, and with no other direct changes to the above line of code, it stopped working, or only works after a page refresh. The console logs "message saved", but I in the client cosnole I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined. But that is just one of the issues, not the ain one.

My goal is to have a message displayed whenever a user joins or leaves the chat room.

What I have is just a server.js and an index.html file.

Here is the relevant IO JS from the server.js file:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
console.log('a user is connected', socket.id); // works
socket.emit('newEntry', { userID: socket.id, // works and is displayed on the front end and console
 description: 'Has joined the chat room!'
});
setTimeout(function() {  // works
socket.emit('testerEvent', { description: 'A custom event named 
testerEvent!'});
}, 4000);

socket.on('clientEvent', function(data) {  // works
  console.log(data);
// here the troubles start
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
console.log('user disconnected', socket.id); // this works 
socket.emit('leaving', { userID: socket.id, // this does not work, is logged on sevrer console, but nothing on client, no error
  description: 'Has left the chat room!'
});
});
})
});
```

The corresponding code in index.html is:

```
 var socket = io(); // init

 socket.emit('clientEvent', 'Sent an event from the client!'); // works
  $(() => { // works
      $("#send").click(()=>{
          sendMessage({name: $("#name").val(), message: 
  $("#message").val()});
      })
      getMessages();

  })
  socket.on('message', addMessages)
  socket.on('testerEvent', function(data){ // works
  console.log(data);

  $("#textdiv").append(` <li class='blueText'> ${data.description} </li> `);
    });
    // this does  not work, its looged on the server side console but nothing happens on client
    socket.on('leaving', function(data){
    console.log(data);

   $("#textdiv").append(` <li class='greenText'> User ${data.userID}  
   ${data.description} </li> `);
      });
    //the following does work, it should append the text to the last message but I can sort that out later.
      socket.on('newEntry', function(data){
      console.log(data);

     $("#textdiv").append(` <li class='blueText'> User ${data.userID}  
     ${data.description} </li> `);
        });
```

So why I the leaving message not working, it looks like everything I do within the socket.on('disconnect', function(){ part does not work.

And as I am getting this previously mentioned error when I try to use slice when I get the time stamp from the following model, how can I change that? I just want the chat to display "posted on [date] at [time].

In server,js, the model is defined:

```
var Message = mongoose.model('Message',{
name : String,
message : String,
time : { type : Date, default: Date.now }
 })
```

And one last thing , how can I clear the console, whenever I restart the browser on localhost 3000, all the old message are displayed and rerendered, even in the new tabs, how can I stop that, it is very tedious to wait for all previous messages to load, esp with error prone code like mine(forgive me, I am new to server side things but I love it:-)).

The github repo: https://github.com/dampopgit/nodejsChat

the code is smaller than it seems, all the help is appreciated.

Localhost3000 and entry point nodemon ./server.js

I know this is one and a half question, but I mainly want to know what I am doing wrong within socket.on('disconnect', function(){} part in server.js.

the next thing would be how do I assign the generated ID to a username, so it says user[username] has joined/left the chat. But first things first. Thanks for having a look.

I also notice that every chat message but the last has the same time stamp, this is bad. Why is that happening. Looks like the whole time stamp should perhaps not be generated from mongoDBs model, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this alone, the problems were many.

```
var Message = mongoose.model('Message',{
name : String,
message : String,
time : { type : Date, default: Date.now }
})
```

Instead of saving the date to mongoDB and not getting a proper time stamp, and getting undefined values if I used any string method, I just did this

```
var fullDate = new Date($.now()).toString();
var datePartialTime = fullDate.slice(16, 25);
var datePartialDate = fullDate.slice(0, 16);
```

And this was the right code to get a message and a popup when a user leaves the chat

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
console.log('user disconnected', socket.id);
if (socket.username == undefined) {
  io.sockets.emit('leaving', { userID: "who values privacy",
    description: 'Has left the chat room!'
});
}

else{
  io.sockets.emit('leaving', { userID: socket.username,
  description: 'Has left the chat room!'
```

});

io.sockets.emit instead of socket.on(the front end code was ok, it was difficult to get hold of this information, due to poor documentation and many version changes, just get used to inspecting the socket object in the console. Still a very good framework, not sure if native websockets are better by now.